# What will be the correct approach in case of StreamBuilders in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, modularity, rxdart, flutter-streambuilder

Let us say that I need access to by "categories stream" on a page. Now the page is modularised such that :

```
Widget/Page A:
build() {
  subWidgetA,
  subWidgetB,
  subWidgetC,
  subWidgetD,
}
```

Now, I need my categories streams inside subWidget A and subWidget D. Should I just declare the streambuilder as the first child inside my build() or declare that streambuilder inside the respective subwidgets.

**Approach 1:**

```
build() {
 StreamBuilder() {
  subWidgetA (data from asyncsnapshot),
  subWidgetB,
  subWidgetC,
  subWidgetD (data from asyncsnapshot),
 } 
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
build() {
 subWidgetA,
 subWidgetB,
 subWidgetC,
 subWidgetD,
}

subWidgetA() {
 StreamBuilder categories () {

 }
}

subWidgetD() {
 StreamBuilder categories () {

 }
}
```

Which approach is better and why ?? Thanks in advance!